# How would I display the field

Tags: reactjs

const button = user;

```
<span>{button} </span>
```

Produces

> react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects
> are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {
> field). If you meant to render a collection
> of children, use an array instead.

```
<span>{button.field} </span>
```

Gives me an empty block.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the user object?

Comment: It basically contains a single value of field= True .

Comment: If the type of your value is boolean you don't see anything. You can check if your value equals true or false (according to your need) for example `button.field ? 'True' : 'False'`